# -ne to $null will not work

Tags: powershell, csv, null

I'm working in PowerShell with a CSV with 13 incremented columns "access1, access2,..", and I am trying to step through and export "crednum" from each row where the access column is not blank, with a new CSV for each column. I've tried (`-ne $null`) and (`-ne " "`) both will just give me the entire content of the crednum column and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```cs
$a = 1

do {
    $column = ("access" + $a)
    $outpath = "C:\Test\" 

    $access = Import-Csv 'C:\import.csv' |
              where {$_.$column -ne " "} |
              select crednum

    $a

    $access | Export-Csv ($outpath + $column + ".csv") -NoTypeInformation

    $a++
} while ($a -le 13)
```

Comment: Try `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.$column)` instead.

Comment: If the column headers are `access1, access2,.` how can you `select crednum` ?

Comment: "*I am trying to export "crednum" from each row where THE access column is not blank"* - each row has 13 access columns. "*both will just give me the entire content of the crednum column*" - does that mean you get every row? Can you be more clear on what you have, and what you want? Try `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.$column)` too

Comment: Please update your question with an example of input and desired output.

Answer (score 2):

An empty string doesn't equal `$null` and it doesn't equal a single space `" "`.  It equals `""`, `''`, or `[String]::Empty`.  However, it's usually best to use the `[String]::IsEmptyOrWhitespace()` function for this sort of thing because it covers more corner cases such as when the column *is* null, or a single space, or an empty string.

You're also importing the entire CSV on each loop.  That's a waste of effort because the entire file has to be processed every iteration.

Try something like this:

```
$Columns = 1..12 | ForEach-Object { "access$_" }

$Access = Import-Csv 'C:\import.csv'

foreach ($Column in $Columns) {
    $Access |
        Where-Object { -not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.$Column) } |
        Select-Object -Property crednum |
        Export-Csv -LiteralPath ($outpath + $Column + ".csv") -NoTypeInformation
}
```